# Return an object from Sinatra::run?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra to handle authentication on a remote server and do a few other simple things. Basically the user authenticates through a page displayed on localhost. After a few exchanges between localhost and the remote server, an object is created that I want to use later. From the moment my object is constructed, no longer need the local Sinatra server.

My Sinatra app is in the form of a class that inherits `Sinatra::Base`.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
# server runs until the user has reached a certain page
# and then returns my business object
object = MySinatraClass.run!

# do stuff with object
```

Is this possible? If not, I could also settle for a solution where I pass a block or function to `MySinatraClass.run!` that I would execute at the right moment.

Comment: If you want to use the return value of the server in this way, you're either using Sinatra for the entirely wrong thing or shouldn't be using Sinatra.

Comment: This smells like an X/Y problem. What is the problem you're actually trying to solve by using Sinatra for authentication?

Comment: Yep, seems you're both right : sinatra was overkill for this. I ended up using a simple TCPServer.open. To clarify I have to do authentication through oauth and the remote website redirects to localhost to pass the access code back, hence the need for a server and basic HTTP handling